# Pairwise matching between 2 sets of points

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I need a method to identify the best combination of pairwise fits between two sets of points such that the overall distance between clustered pairs is minimised.  It seems possibly suited to k-means (with 'n' pairs if a max/min cluster size constraint of 2 is possible) but I'm not aware of any functions that can cluster between 2 sets.  Does anyone know of an appropriate function or alternative clustering method?

As a starting point, it looks like the solution following sets of points:

```
set1 <- data.frame(id=c('A','B','C'), x = c(3,4,7), y = c(4,2,6))
set2 <- data.frame(id=c('X','Y','Z'), x = c(2,5,8), y = c(5,6,7))
```

... is AX, BY, CZ:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to cluster pairs where each pair consist of a point from each set? So in your example it has to be 3 clusters where each cluster is a pair drawing a point from each set?

Comment: Yes to both questions!

Comment: And you would define the centroid of the cluster by calculating the mean of the points in the cluster even if they belong to different sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not cluster analysis. It's not about finding structural components in your data set.

Instead, what you are looking for is a `JOIN` of the two data sets.

If you allow each point to map to multiple points in the other data set, then it is a **nearest neighbor join**. Otherwise, I'm not sure what to call it, but I know an algorithm for solving it:

The [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), also known as Kuhn–Munkres algorithm or Munkres assignment algorithm. The simplest explanation is as follows:

1. You have `n` producers
2. You have `m` consumers, possibly m != n, but lest assume m=n.
3. You want to maximize your profits, by e.g. minimizing transportation cost to get the products from the producers to the consumers

So you build a matrix of shipping costs, listing the costs for every pair of producers and consumers. The Hungarian algorithm can then be used to find the best mapping. (Which *may* involve not always choosing the nearest neighbor.)

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Anoiny-Mousse's answer, this R implementation that works for me:

```
require(clue)
dist_mat = fields::rdist(set1[,2:3], set2[,2:3])
soln = solve_LSAP(dist_mat)
data.frame(set1 = set1$id, set2 = set2$id[soln])
  set1 set2
1    A    X
2    B    Y
3    C    Z
```